# Avoid Overwriting Downloaded PDFs with Same Filename using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When downloading PDF URLs from an Excel file using Selenium in Python, a common issue arises where files with the same filename get overwritten during the download process. This problem occurs because multiple PDFs have identical filenames, leading to the last downloaded file overwriting the previously downloaded ones. As a result, at the end of the download process, only one file remains with the shared filename, discarding all the others. The task at hand is to devise a solution using Selenium in Python to prevent the overwriting of downloaded PDFs with identical filenames. Currently, the code loops through the dataframe, downloads each PDF URL, and saves it into a designated destination folder. However, due to the shared filenames, the files overwrite each other, leading to a loss of data.

**What I Have Tried:**
I am using Selenium in Python to download PDFs from a list of URLs stored in an Excel file. I have set up the necessary options for the Chrome webdriver and implemented the logic to download the PDFs one by one by looping through a DataFrame containing the URLs and corresponding filenames.

**Expectations:**

My goal is to modify the downloading process to avoid overwriting PDFs with the same filename. Currently, when multiple PDFs have the same filename, the last downloaded file overwrites the previously downloaded ones, resulting in a loss of data. Instead, I expect the downloaded files to be saved with unique filenames, such as filename.pdf, filename (1).pdf, filename (2).pdf, and so on, for each consecutive download, to preserve all the files.

**Packages and Options Imported:**

*Here are the packages and options I have imported for my Selenium script:*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import os
import warnings
import pyperclip
import Xlib.display
from pyvirtualdisplay.display import Display

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
options.add_argument("--disable-cache")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'download.default_directory': file_path})
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution is to import os then `os.listdir()` if `file_name` is in this list, simply save the name by incrementing name.

Comment: May I know how to compare with the downloaded filename with the existing one when downloaded file gets overwritten as soon as download is complete. We can not stop and compare.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to check for the presence of the filename in the given download directory in each iteration/loop.

As you mentioned, you're looping through a DataFrame containing the URLs and corresponding filenames. So in each looping, you should

1. check for the presence of the filename in the given directory.
2. you can enumerate the loop to get the loop index and that can be used to make the filenames unique.
3. if the filename is already there in the directory, rename it with `filename_i` (i is for the loop index, for example, 1,2,3,4, ........So `filename_1`, `filename_2` and so on)
4. next, get the URL from the dataframe and execute the download operation.

The loop will keep repeating the steps from point 1 to point 4 and at the end, you'll get all files downloaded in the given directory with unique filenames.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but in the Dataframe only I have the URL and there is no filename column is present. My selenium code iterates over the PDF Urls and download it one by one. The problem here is, after downloading one PDF URL, it overwrites the earlier filename.pdf which is causing loss of data. May I know if there is any option or argument present in Selenium where we can disable this overwriting and get filename (i).pdf

Comment: you could hardcode the filename if it's the same for all the URLs. Otherwise, I would be able to help if you could provide a set of sample URLs or a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the problem and thus provide you some way around to solve it.